# How to drop a row by specific row name/value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to drop the row `Name == 30`?

How about dropping 2 rows at the same time, say `Name == 30` and `Name == 40`?

```
Name     Date    sales   discount  net_sales 

20     20060331   2.709       NaN      2.709 
30     20060630   6.590       NaN      6.590
40     20060930  10.103       NaN     10.103 
50     20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df[df.Name.ne(30)]` or `df[df.Name!=30]`

Comment: `df[~df.Name.eq(30)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Series.ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html:)

```
df[df['Name'].ne(30)]
```

or if 30 is `str`

```
df[df['Name'].ne('30')]
```

Output:

```
   Name      Date   sales  discount  net_sales
0    20  20060331   2.709       NaN      2.709
2    40  20060930  10.103       NaN     10.103
3    50  20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915
```

---

To drop more than 1  you need to use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[~df['Name'].isin([20,30])]
```

---

```
   Name      Date   sales  discount  net_sales
2    40  20060930  10.103       NaN     10.103
3    50  20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915
```

Use to drop column 5:

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin([5])]
```

or

```
df.loc[:,df.columns != 5]
```

Comment: Also, I used `df = df.iloc[:, :-1]` to drop the last column, do you know how I can drop the last 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

you can use index of filterd rows like below

```py
df.drop(df[df["Name"]==30].index, inplace=True)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.drop(df[df.Name.eq(30)].index)
```

or

```
df[~df.Name.eq(30)]
```